# GroovyCastException in Katalon when performing Selenium explicit wait

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio, webdriverwait

I am trying to perform an explicit wait in Katalon (which uses Groovy). I have the following code :

```
// wait on page change to "Dashboard"
    WebDriverWait dashboardChangeWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
    /* This is causing the following Exception : 
     *   - GroovyCastException : Attempt to cast 'true' with class 'java.lang.Boolean' to class
     *      'org.openqa.selenium.WebElement'
     * */
    WebElement element = dashboardChangeWait.until(
        ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.cssSelector('.breadcrumb-item.active'), "DASHBOARD"))
```

which is giving me a `GroovyCastException`. I know that `WebDriverWait.until` takes a `Function` (yay, JavaScript-like coding!) argument, and that `ExpectedConditions.textToBe` [returns a `ExpectedCondition<Boolean>`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBe-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-) and `until`'s signature is `V org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(Function<Object, Object<V>> arg0)` . Is there a way to perform this type of wait in Katalon, that avoids this issue?

Comment: /* Katalon's `WebUI` contains all kinds of wait methods, but none that wait for an element to contain a certain text. */

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close. The *ExpectedConditions* method [**`textToBe()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#textToBe-org.openqa.selenium.By-java.lang.String-) is defined as follows:

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.lang.Boolean> textToBe(By locator, java.lang.String value)

An expectation for checking WebElement with given locator has specific text

Parameters:
locator - used to find the element
value - used as expected text

Returns:
Boolean true when element has text value equal to @value
```

So you just need to change the return type to **`boolean`** instead of `WebElement` as follows:

```
Boolean status = dashboardChangeWait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBe(By.cssSelector('.breadcrumb-item.active'), "DASHBOARD"))
```